# Can't print data from database in react. Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productname')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, frontend

```
router.get("/product",async(req,res) => {
        try {
            const data = await Product.find({});
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

The code above fetches the data from database successfully and also prints in the console.
Now in frontend

```
function Product() {
    useEffect (() => {
        fetchItems();
    },[]);

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async() => {
        const data = await fetch('/product',{
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            credentials: "include"
        });
        const items = await data.json();
        setItems(items);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Product Page</h1>
            {
                items.map(item => {
                    <p>{item.product.productname} {item.product.producttype} {item.product.productprice}</p>
                })
            }

        </div>
    )
}
```

I can't print any items as I am getting a type error. The name of the collection is products.

Comment: Well the error is pretty self-explanatory. `item.product` is undefined, so trying to do `item.product.productname` produces that error. Have you printed `items` to see that the data is the shape you think it is?

Comment: I am getting this error Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, productname, productprice, producttype}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @RitikSingh can you please show the response by 

`const items = await data.json();
console.log('<<== items ==>> ', items);
setItems(items);`
Thanks!

Comment: @JIGNESHPATEL Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, productname, productprice, producttype}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @RitikSingh try `npm i core-js` put this line into the first line of your `index.js` file. `import core-js`. 
And replace map with `items && items.map(item => { return ( <p>{item.product.productname} {item.product.producttype} {item.product.productprice}</p>) })`
Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your items render first and your state set after return it's common issue in react
just do:

```
 return (
    <div>
        <h1>Product Page</h1>
        {(items?.length > 0) &&
            items?.map(item => {
                <p>{item?.product?.productname} {item?.product?.producttype} {item?.product?.productprice}</p>
            })
        }
    </div>
)
```